# How to delay before execution

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

I'm trying to make simple groovy script in Eclipse.
I've noticed that script always executes after some delay. About half of second delay. In the same time an equivalent java code executes without of delay. The same is true when I run jar files in console.

What is the reason for that?

Comment: A hunch; It has a lot more classes to load (all the groovy internals)

Answer (score 1):

I confirmed my hunch. When running a simple hello world program in Java:

```
public class Main {     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }    
}
```

with `-XX:+TraceClassLoading`, I can see it loads 415 classes before the output.

But for the same program in groovy:

```
class GMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        println "Hello World"    
    }
}
```

it loads 1665 classes before output.

Class loading takes a lot of time, (afaik since it typically includes hard disk I/O), so that would account for at least part of the longer delay. But in general, the groovy runtime just does *more* on start-up, so it takes longer.

Comment: and if annotate groovy class with @groovy.transform.CompileStatic ?

Comment: @daggett More, it loads 1769

Comment: And just to finish it, could you give the groovy&java versions, and try with groovy-all only lib and groovy-all-indy. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @daggett There would probably not be much difference. Besides, I'm not a benchmarking service.